# People Search from Linkedin using People Search API and UrlFetchAPI #Linkedin #Google Spread Sheet

Tags: linkedin-api, urlfetch

My objective is to get people count (On Linkedin) of a company per country. And This information I want in Google Spread sheet.

After lot of search on Linkedin API page and Here itself - I could make below script. It runs without any error. I have created API Keys and Secret Codes on Linkedin API page.

But no data is returned by the script in my spreadsheet.

And If I check Linkedin People Search API for me - I see that script has gone there to get the data as API calls going up each time I run It.

I would appreciate help to how to solve this problem.

Thnx and Regards,
Pramesh Tyagi

The script is as below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "PeopleSearch",
    functionName : "PeopleSearch"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("PeopleSearch", entries);
};

function PeopleSearch() { //loop 1


   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();     
   var LinkedinTalent = ss.getSheetByName("LinkedinTalent");
   var CMPNY = ss.getSheetByName("Company");   
   var PRMTR = ss.getSheetByName("PRMTR");

   var APIKey = PRMTR.getRange(2,1).getValue();//API Key
   var SecretKey = PRMTR.getRange(2,2).getValue();//Secret Key


    var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("linkedIn");
    oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken");
    oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken");
    oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize");
    oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(APIKey);
    oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(SecretKey);
    var requestData = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "linkedIn",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
    };
    var url="https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?company-name=Google&current-company=true"

    var result = "";
    try{
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData).getContentText();    
    }catch (erro){
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("test", "error found \n" + erro);
    }

   LinkedinTalent.getRange(1,1).setValue(result);  

  }
```

Comment: Hi Pramesh. I am also working on a project that has same functionality as mentioned above. I was trying to implement the above script but it showed me an error saying "Script is using OAuthConfig which has been shut down. Learn more at http://goo.gl/IwCSaV". I am stuck at this point on how to write the config. Please help me out. Thank You.

Comment: Sorry - I lost interest in the project and so did not follow it. Hope u were able to resolve it